# How to reset setInterval function using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `useInterval` hook, wrote by Dan Abramov from [here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

How can I reset counter? As example by click on button?

Code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-voice-fe4hq)

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  const resetInterval = () => {};

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button ocClick={resetInterval}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reset the counter, call `setCount(0)` from `resetInterval`:

**Note:** you misspelled `onClick` on the button.

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  const resetInterval = () => setCount(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={resetInterval}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

To stop/resume the interval you can refactor `useInterval` to return a `toggleRunning` function, and the current `running` status.

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();
  const intervalId = useRef(null);
  const [currentDelay, setDelay] = useState(delay);

  const toggleRunning = useCallback(
    () => setDelay(currentDelay => (currentDelay === null ? delay : null)),
    [delay]
  );

  const clear = useCallback(() => clearInterval(intervalId.current), []);

  // Remember the latest function.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    if (intervalId.current) clear();

    if (currentDelay !== null) {
      intervalId.current = setInterval(tick, currentDelay);
    }

    return clear;
  }, [currentDelay, clear]);

  return [toggleRunning, !!currentDelay];
}
```

Working example with Reset and Pause/Resume ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/confident-williams-kdzdk))

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback, Fragment } = React;

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const [toggle, running] = useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, 100);

  const resetCounter = () => setCount(0);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={resetCounter}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={toggle}>{running ? "Pause" : "Resume"}</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();
  const intervalId = useRef(null);
  const [currentDelay, setDelay] = useState(delay);

  const toggleRunning = useCallback(
    () => setDelay(currentDelay => (currentDelay === null ? delay : null)),
    [delay]
  );

  const clear = useCallback(() => clearInterval(intervalId.current), []);

  // Remember the latest function.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    if (intervalId.current) clear();

    if (currentDelay !== null) {
      intervalId.current = setInterval(tick, currentDelay);
    }

    return clear;
  }, [currentDelay, clear]);

  return [toggleRunning, !!currentDelay];
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, root);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Nope. Just resets the number to 0.

Comment: Are you looking for interval clearing, resetting the number to 0, or both?

Comment: It's just you using `resetInterval` function which reset the counter...

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to `clearInterval` and stop/reset the counter, check the next example:

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const intervalId = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(prev => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(0);
        }}
      >
        Reset Counter and Continue Counting
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(0);
          clearInterval(intervalId.current);
        }}
      >
        Reset and Stop Count
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clearInterval(intervalId.current);
        }}
      >
        Stop Count and Clear Interval
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56952038-ClearIntervalOnClick]

Comment: Do we not need `clearInterval(intervalId.current)` in the "Reset Counter" click handler also?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do... it's pretty clear if you want to reset the counter and stop it from counting again you can add `clearInterval`

Comment: I guess OP wants to do that, this is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the state to 0

```
 const resetInterval = () => {setCount(0)};

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={resetInterval}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
```

It seems that you have mistyped onClick and that is why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you can use an extra `reset` state, pass it to `useInterval`, change this state somehow on every reset change (I am simply incrementing it), then use this state in a ref like `callback` and compare the current and the old one in `useInterval`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [delay, setDelay] = React.useState(1000);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = React.useState(true);
  const [reset, setReset] = React.useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, isRunning ? delay : null, reset);

  function handleDelayChange(e) {
    setDelay(Number(e.target.value));
  }

  function handleIsRunningChange(e) {
    setIsRunning(e.target.checked);
  }

  function handleResetChange() {
    setReset(c => c + 1);
    setCount(0);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={isRunning} onChange={handleIsRunningChange} /> Running
      <br />
      <input value={delay} onChange={handleDelayChange} />
      <button onClick={handleResetChange}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}

function useInterval(callback, delay, reset) {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef();
  const savedReset = React.useRef();
  // Remember the latest function.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
    savedReset.current = reset;
  }, [callback, reset]);

  // Set up the interval.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null || reset !== savedReset.current) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => {console.log("cleared", id); clearInterval(id)};
    }
  }, [delay, reset]);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement);
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-glitter-lxpsh)